# ASP.NET Web Control for Progressing Bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I would like to know how can I create a simple progressing bar, that could show to a user a friendly look for a variable with values from 0 to 100%.

This variable has been populated with a method in my code.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your time.
I am using C# and asp.net 4[image]

The idea is smt like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery plug in for this check the following links

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

[jQuery.UI ProgressBar Widget](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/jqueryui_progressbar_widget.html)

Comment: do yo know any web control from MS=?